# How to set environment variable for my user from cronjob in debian linux?

Tags: python, cron, environment-variables

I was trying to set environment variable from my cronjob. Apparently crontab is running on different shell than normal scripts when i run them on my user.

This is my crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/jan_necinski_binance/miniconda3/bin/python gethistoricals.py >> output.txt
```

and this is my file that is running in crontab:

```
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
import os

client = Client(os.getenv('API_KEY'), os.getenv('API_SECRET'))

def GetHistoricalData(symbol: str, ST: int, LT: int, interval: str, to: str):
    df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, str(LT) + ' days ago UTC', to))
    closes = pd.DataFrame(df[4])
    closes.columns = ['Close']
    closes['ST'] = closes.Close.rolling(ST - 1).sum()
    closes['LT'] = closes.Close.rolling(LT - 1).sum()
    closes.dropna(inplace=True)
    return closes

def HistST(hist):
    histST = str(hist['ST'].values[0])
    return histST

def HistLT(hist):
    histLT = str(hist['LT'].values[0])
    return histLT

os.environ['ST'] = HistST(GetHistoricalData('ATOMUSDT', 7, 25, '1d', '1 day ago UTC'))
os.environ['LT'] = HistLT(GetHistoricalData('ATOMUSDT', 7, 25, '1d', '1 day ago UTC'))

print(os.getenv('ST'))
print('cronjob works correctly')
```

So to sum up **my problem is that crontab sets environment variable in different enviroment so my scripts cannot acces them. Please help!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron subsystem does not set environment variables. I'll bet you're setting those env vars in your *~/.bashrc*. That startup script is not read by non-interactive shells such as those launched by cron. The easiest way to deal with this is to put your env vars in a separate script (I like to name it *~/.environ*) then source that file in your *~/.bashrc* and your cron job. For example:

```
* * * * * source ~/.environ; /home/jan_necinski_binance/miniconda3/bin/python gethistoricals.py >> output.txt
```

Comment: `&&` is much better than `;`